# (cocos2d-x) How to debug android native crash with anonymous and unknown backtrace?

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I use cocos2d-x and ndk-build to build app on arm64. But when i run it on 64bit device, the app crash randomly with error signal 11 (SIGSEGV), and the backtrace shows anonymous and unknown.

I use cocos2d-x 3.17.1, ndk 16, Android Studio 3.4.1, gradle tools 3.2.0 and gradle wrapper 4.6.
I tried ndk-stack but it didn't show me more useful information.

This is the log in the Logcat.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/chiron/chiron:8.0.0/OPR1.170623.027/V10.3.1.0.ODECNXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 17667, tid: 17711, name: GLThread 135726  >>> com.test.myapp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x72adf0f460
     x0   00000072bc089378  x1   0000000000000000  x2   fffd8072bc08bc18  x3   fffd8072bb3f4950
     x4   00000000ee1763de  x5   fffd8072bc096c88  x6   ff687373604f6d64  x7   7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
     x8   00000072b09a9f08  x9   00000072b09a9f00  x10  fffffffffffffffb  x11  00000072a9bcc6c8
     x12  00000072aceade40  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000697474  x15  00000072a9ac6c10
     x16  0000000000000001  x17  fffa0072a9ac58c8  x18  0000000000000012  x19  00000072b09a9e98
     x20  fffd8072a9bc31e0  x21  00000072a9bcfa00  x22  00000072bc0893d8  x23  00000072ac48ab40
     x24  00000072b162cca8  x25  00000072ade90978  x26  00000072a94d0c20  x27  00000072a99953e0
     x28  00000072a9995070  x29  00000072b0da8080  x30  fffd8072a9ac48a0
     sp   00000072b0da8060  pc   00000072adf0f460  pstate 0000000080000000
 backtrace:
     #00 pc 0000000000078460  <anonymous:00000072ade97000>
     #01 pc fffd8072a9ac489c  <unknown>
```

This is the log with ndk-stack

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/chiron/chiron:8.0.0/OPR1.170623.027/V10.3.1.0.ODECNXM:user/release-keys'
pid: 17667, tid: 17711, name: GLThread 135726  >>> com.test.myapp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x72adf0f460
Stack frame #00 pc 0000000000078460  <anonymous:00000072ade97000>
Stack frame #01 pc fffd8072a9ac489c  <unknown>
```

I expect the backtrace and ndk-stack can show me where the problem is, but it shows only anonymous and unknown.

Comment: Are you building your game in release mode or debug mode?

Comment: both debug and release mode.

Comment: Does this happen with the cocos2d-x samples or it's specific to your app? Also, have you tried to debug it live so you can see where it crashes?

Comment: From what I understand this is a 64-bit issue only, correct?